# Design Pattern for an modular enterprise application

Tags: jakarta-ee, design-patterns, database-design, content-management-system, jackrabbit

We are developing a Java based system and we are looking for the best design pattern that will grow with the application even as more modules will be added in course of time
goals are:

- Modular where there is the core module and other modules will inherit basic functionalities from.
- then that other modules are individual components but shares data across other modules
- On the admin side  the modules can be assigned to a certain user

For example, student will be assigned, payment, forum, course, if it's a general customer payment, shopping, etc. If a student wants to shop, you upgrade his account and add shopping module to him and in his account, update the course to show he bought a book, for example, "Concurreny in Java."

- Modules can be turned on and off without affecting the stability of the application.
- I thinking also of using jackrabbit due to the management of the contents.  Am I wrong? References both positive and negative?

Which is the **best design pattern that will work with us**?  Any **advice you would recommend or materials I can look at**?

How can we implement the database design to almost perfection?  **references you might have ?**

Any more advice will be accepted and is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

A modular pattern that I've had good success with in the past is the message bus.  Essentially, the Student (or Professor or Admin etc) doesn't talk directly to the Payment or Forum or Course etc. module, instead all communication is done via a message bus (e.g. Student sends a message to the bus, which sends the message to Forum).  This message bus can be a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) or [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html), or this could be a piece of third party software such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/); each of these has its pros and cons that you'll need to weigh, but you're not completely locked into your decision - I worked on a project where we switched from Amazon SQS to RabbitMQ, and my job of rewriting the message format wasn't that complicated.

Nice things about messaging:

1. Robustness.  If you use a persistent queue (meaning that messages are saved to a database) then you can withstand a program crash with minimal loss of data.  In addition, the client modules (Student/Professor/Admin), service modules (Payment, Forum, Course), and message bus typically operate in separate memory spaces (they each have their own thread pools, and data is copied between them instead of being directly shared between them), so if one module crashes it won't take the other modules down with it (unless it's the message bus that crashes, in which case the other modules are still intact but they've got to spin/sleep until the bus comes back online).
2. Scalability.  Concurrent and distributed systems are often built on a messaging model; for example, messaging is an intrinsic part of concurrent languages and libraries like Erlang and Akka.  The message bus will be a bottleneck if you're not careful, though, but if you don't trust yourself to implement it well then there are several good third party libraries to choose from.
3. Modularity.  If you want to add a new module then you just need to write it to interoperate with your message bus - you don't need to write separate interfaces for it to talk to all of the other modules.  Removing a module is just as easy - just have the message bus route its messages to dead letter storage.  And things like access controls are easy to implement via the message bus - if a Student doesn't have access to the Admin module, then the message bus simply routs the erroneous messages to dead letter storage or to an exception queue.

The primary disadvantage of messaging is its efficiency - modules communicate by copying data instead of by granting direct access.  However, in the long run you'll find that this will make it much easier to implement your modules using multi-threading, which will probably result in a net efficiency gain.

Comment: Here's a Java Messaging Service tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/jms_tutorialTOC.html

Comment: Here is basic a RabbitMQ example of producer - consumer communication http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-java-client/file/default/test/src/com/rabbitmq/examples/ConfirmDontLoseMessages.java